# How to mock open file and raise if path does not exists?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

I'am facing a problem when testing a function that reads the first line of a file and raises an `Exception` when the path of the file doesn't exist.

Current code:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
from pytest import raises
from os.path import exists

def read_from_file(file_path):
    if not exists(file_path):
        raise Exception("File does not exists!")
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()[0]

@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="Correct string\nWrong string\nWrong string")
@patch("os.path.exists", return_value=True)
def test_read_file_and_returns_the_correct_string_with_multiple_lines(mock_os, mock_file):
    result = read_from_file("xyz")
    mock_file.assert_called_once_with("xyz", "r")
    assert result == "Correct string"

@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="Correct string")
@patch("os.path.exists", return_value=False)
def test_throws_exception_when_file_doesnt_exist(mock_os, mock_file):
    with raises(Exception):
        read_from_file("xyz")
```

The decorators `@patch("os.path.exists", return_value=True)` and `@patch("os.path.exists", return_value=False)` seems to have no effect in both tests.

How can I mock the existence of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises because the `read_from_file` directly imports `exists` from `os.path` and uses it, but the mock targets `os.path.exists`, which does not affect the direct import. Hence, the real function gets executed instead of the mock.

Change `read_from_file` to this:

```py
import os.path

def read_from_file(file_path):
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        raise Exception("File does not exist!")
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT. Bad answer, @elmiomar code is correct to me.

The problem you're facing is related to the order of the `@patch` decorators. The decorators are applied from the innermost to the outermost. So, in your tests, the `mock_file` argument corresponds to `builtins.open`, and the `mock_os` argument corresponds to `os.path.exists`.

When you mock multiple objects, the mocked objects are passed to the test function in the order the patch decorators appear. In your case, you should switch the order of the mock parameters in the function signature to match the decorators.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
from pytest import raises
from os.path import exists

def read_from_file(file_path):
    if not exists(file_path):
        raise Exception("File does not exists!")
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()[0]

@patch("os.path.exists", return_value=True)
@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="Correct string\nWrong string\nWrong string")
def test_read_file_and_returns_the_correct_string_with_multiple_lines(mock_file, mock_os):
    result = read_from_file("xyz")
    mock_file.assert_called_once_with("xyz", "r")
    assert result == "Correct string"

@patch("os.path.exists", return_value=False)
@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="Correct string")
def test_throws_exception_when_file_doesnt_exist(mock_file, mock_os):
    with raises(Exception):
        read_from_file("xyz")
```

Comment: You switched the patches order and the arguments order, which doesn't change anything. The original order is fine. The problem is that they are mocking `os.path.exists` but in the function `read_from_file`  they are calling `exists` directly, which doesn't use the mock.

Comment: my bad. was sure and didn't check, you are correct.